# Why is the career badge pink?

Tags: discussion, badges

Any reason why the [career badge](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/badges/60/career) is pink?

I noticed it on someones [profile](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/897/grandmasterb) and it sparked my curiosity.

Answer (score 8):

ChrisF and Anna Lear answered why it's different, so I'm not going to repeat them.

And [Jin](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1685/jin), Stack Exchange's designer-in-residence, would be able to answer definitively as to why it's *specifically* pink.

But I always understood the badges to be abstractions of the Post-It Note:

#### Regular Badge

[image: Yellow Post-It Notes]

#### Tag Badge

[image: Pink Post-It Notes]

Comment: I never thought of that, but now you mention it it's obvious.

Comment: Mark got it right. I just happened to have pink stickies on my desk when I designed the theme..

Answer (score 4):

Badges awarded for upvotes received in a particular tag (such as [career](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career)) have a different style to differentiate them from the other kind of badges. For example, I have a badge for the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag here on meta and it's shown in pink as well.

As for why it's pink instead of any other colour... not a clue. That's probably a question only [Jin ♦](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1685/jin) can answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's a tag badge.

There are two kinds of badges:

- [general badges](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/badges) awarded for specific things
- [tag badges](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/badges?tab=tags) awarded "These badges are awarded for participating in **non community-wiki questions** with particular tags."

Tag badges can be revoked if you fall below the criteria.

Comment: "non community-wiki questions" So what if you acquire 50 votes for a question before it goes wiki. Do those prior wiki votes count, or are they all dismissed once it turns wiki?

Comment: @John - I *think* votes acquired before a question/answer goes CW still count, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that's because it's a badge for a tag (ie. they received 100 upvotes in that tag). It's not the same as a "Nice Answer" badge.